# Angular Datatables - Select only filtered rows

Tags: html, angular-datatables

I am rendering my `DataTable` the angular way, I added a checkbox per row and a `select all` checkbox at the top. The problem is that for example, I filter the rows using the search box if I check the `select all` it checks all the rows. What do I do so that when the `select all` checkbox is clicked, it only checks the visible rows after the filtering.

**Html**

```
<table id="tblAvailable" datatable="ng" dt-options="mainCtrl.dtOptions" dt-instance="mainCtrl.dtInstance" dt-column-defs="mainCtrl.dtColumnDefs" class="table table-responsive table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Ref. #</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Applied Amount</th>
            <th>New Amount</th>
            <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="mainCtrl.selectAll" ng-click="mainCtrl.toggleAll(mainCtrl.selectAll)" ng-change="mainCtrl.update()"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="Item in mainCtrl.newLineDetails" ng-if="Item.Amount > 0">
            <td>{{Item.Id}}</td>
            <td>{{Item.Type.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{Item.Category.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{Item.Amount | number:2}}</td>
            <td><input type="number" ng-disabled="Item.isSelected == false" id="Amount" name="Amount" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" ng-model="Item.Amount" ng-min="1" ng-max="Item.Amount" ng-required="Item.isSelected == true" ng-change="mainCtrl.updateForFreeUps()"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="Item.isSelected" ng-change="mainCtrl.toggleOne(Item.Id)"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Ctrl**

```
self.toggleAll = function(selectAll) {
    angular.forEach(self.newLineDetails, function (value, index) {
        self.newLineDetails[index]["isSelected"] = selectAll;
        if (selectAll == false) {
            self.newLineDetails[index]["Amount"] = null;
        }
    })

}
self.toggleOne = function (Id) {
    for (var i = 0, len = self.newLineDetails.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (self.newLineDetails[i]["Id"] == Id) {
            self.newLineDetails[i]["Amount"] = null;
            self.selectAll = false;
            self.update();
            return;
        }
    }
    self.selectAll = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *must* go through the DataTables API. DT remove and inject DOM nodes from a "shadow table" so just manipulating DOM will only have apparently (not real) effect until next redraw. Fortunately you have already implemented a `dtInstance`.

From 1.10.6 the most convenient way to iterate through rows, columns or cells is the `every` method. See this plunkr -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/NOP5u4PUcwVOBFUtBkBi?p=preview**

```
$scope.$watch('settings.selectAll', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal == oldVal) return
  var api = $scope.dtInstance.DataTable;
  api.rows({ search:'applied' }).every(function() {
    api.cell({ row:this.index(), column:0 })
     .nodes()
     .to$()
     .find('input')
     .prop('checked', $scope.settings.selectAll);
  })
  $scope.dtInstance.DataTable.draw()
})
```

Here the checkbox is in column 0; the code can be translated into

- cycle through all rows
- get the first column
- convert to jQuery instance
- find the `<input>`
- update the `checked` status

Some notes about your `selectAll` checkbox :

- best to use an object as `ng-model`, in the example I have used a `settings.selectAll` literal
- `ng-click` does not work effectively with checkboxes, if you really want to use a directive, use `ng-change` only
- since you are using a `ng-model`, you can just `$watch` that value, calling `mainCtrl.toggleAll(mainCtrl.selectAll)` is "obscure"

Comment: I saw your plunker and I searched 'Accountant' in the search box, it returned two results and then when I clicked the checkAll checkbox it checked all the items, not just the filtered items.

Comment: @klent, OK, did not thought of that :( Just add  `{ search: applied }` as row selector, then it will only iterate over filtered rows.  See above. Have updated the plunkr as well.

Comment: thanks. my next problem is that even though the checkbox is checked the model of the checkbox remains false.

Comment: @klent, OK, have forked the plunkr -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/yvFiYcDmEWvVxgyVMQLl?p=preview** where the checkboxes refer to a `ng-model`, `checked` .  Simply `$scope.data[this.index()].checked = $scope.settings.selectAll` have commented out the internal update from the loop. Look in the console to see how the `checked` prop changes.

Comment: @davidkonrad what if i want to select all rows for active page. example, if i have total 50 rows, I've added pagination and each pagination has 10 rows. So how can i select all rows from active pagination.

Comment: @UmairRazzaq, I am pretty sure you can do that by `api.rows({ search:'applied', page: 'current'  }).every(..` ...

Comment: Thanks yes I've implemented it with `page:'current'`, since i only need pagination so removed search. Thanks again...

Comment: In my case `$scope.approvalTransList[this.index()].checked = $scope.settings.selectAll;` not working for select all. Though its working the other (jquery) way. But checkbox looks like checked visually but value in ng-modal is empty. Any clue on this one?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways for solving this problem:
1) You can write change function for select all checkbox. In that function first you should filter all of your data after that check them.
2) You can copy your main data to another variable (we call it x for now). after that show x in table (not your main resource). when you want to filter the rows using the search box filter main data and past it into the x variable when you want to use it for check or add etc use x variable